# How do I search and replace an attibute value in my Nokogiri doc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

How do I replace an attribute value in my Nokogiri doc?  I identified the attribute in question using:

```
doc.xpath("//pre[@class='text-results']").xpath("meta[@http-equiv='Content-Type']").attr("content").to_s
```

but when I try and assign a different value to it, nothing is getting returned in my Rails console, which leads me to believe I'm not doing it right:

```
2.3.0 :027 > doc.xpath("//pre[@class='text-results']").xpath("meta[@http-equiv='Content-Type']").attr("content") = "text/html; charset=iso8849";
2.3.0 :028 >
```

Error in response to answer given:

```
2.3.0 :005 > doc.xpath("//pre[@class='text-results']").xpath("meta[@http-equiv='Content-Type']")["content"] = "text/html; charset=iso8849"
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]=' for #<Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet:0x007f820271c628>
Did you mean?  []
from (irb):5
from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I'm using Rails 4.2.7.

Comment: I'd recommend using a spelling-checker. Stack Overflow is an online reference book, where spelling and grammar do matter.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". When asking about code you've written we need the minimal input data that demonstrates the problem. In this case it would be the minimum XML. Without that we have to generate something that we think fits. That leads to inaccuracy in answers and wastes our time keeping us from helping others. So please help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `[]=` method

```
node["content"] = "text/html; charset=iso8849"
```

If you want to update the first one

```
doc.xpath("//pre[@class='text-results']").xpath("meta[@http-equiv='Content-Type']").first["content"] = "text/html; charset=iso8849"
```

Or every node

```
doc.xpath("//pre[@class='text-results']").xpath("meta[@http-equiv='Content-Type']").each { |node| node["content"] = "text/html; charset=iso8849" }
```

Comment: When I tried your suggestion, I got the error, "NoMethodError: undefined method `[]=' for #<Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet".  I included the complete output in an edit to my question.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer. I don't know which node you want to update.

Comment: Instead of `search`, `xpath` or `css` followed by `first`, use `at` or one of its variants `at_css` or `at_xpath`.